# Apache Nifi - Implementing While True and Wait

Tags: apache-nifi

In Nifi, I would like to implement the following logic in Nifi.

```
while(true) {
  prj_result = invoke_prj_Rest_EndPoint();
  prjs_list = prjs_list["prjs"];
  for prj in prjs_list:
       emp_response = invoke_emp_rest_Endpoint(prj["id"]);
       next_cursor = emp_response["meta"]["next_cursor"];
       while next_cursor:
         sleep(10 secs);
         emps = emp_response["emps"];
         for emp in emps:
             emp["mod_time"] = now();
         loadEmpDataToS3()
  sleep(5Mins)
}
```

Approach I have so far,

[image]

For while(true) --> I am initializing a param i = 1 and checking $(i:eq(1)) and not incrementing. Is there a better approach?
For Sleep or not sure what is the best approach?
Also, Not sure how to implement for and prj in prjs_list and internal while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GenerateFlowFile - is already kind a "while(true)" - it will generate flowfile according to a schedule.

after first invokehttp split response by "prjs" to multiple flowfiles. if response is json you can use [SplitJson](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.20.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.SplitJson/index.html)

after splitting - make required transformation on each "prj" flowfile and then call invokehttp - again in scheduling you can set every 10 sec.

So, flow could look like this:

```
      1 GenerateFlowFile
1 --> 2 InvokeHttp        first
2 --> 3 SplitJson         by $.prjs
3 --> 4 EvaluateJsonPath  extract $.prj.id
4 --> 5 InvokeHttp        second with 10 sec schedule
5 --> 6 transform and put to s3
5 --> 7 EvaluateJsonPath  extract $.meta.next_cursor
7 --> 8 route on attribute (next_cursor is not empty)
8 --> 5
```

[image: plantuml]